# Conditional Move Exchange Email to Junk E-mail

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange

On my Exchange 2003 server, I am using SpamAssassin for Windows which tags each spam message as

```
*****SPAM*****
```

in the subject line.  How can I automatically move these emails to each user's Junk E-mail folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the built in IMF (Intelligent Message Filter) feature.  You can look for specific tags in the subject line, then assign them an SCL value.  I would assign it the highest value which is 9.  Then in your SCL config make sure that at messages of at least value 9 are moved automatically into the junk folder.  We've been doing this on our Exchange 2003 system for years.

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/microsoft-exchange-intelligent-message-filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Couple options:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.10.weightlists.aspx

http://www.slipstick.com/rules/

Comment: Can rules be created on the Server-Side?

Comment: No they can't in Exchange 2003.

Comment: Hm, are you sure? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142571%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx